# How do correct the height of the transformer in circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)
node[transformer] (T) {};
\draw (T.B1)
to [D] (3,0)
to [R] (3,-2.1)
to [short] (T.B2);
\draw (3,0)
to [vR] (6,0)
to [R] (6,-2.1)
to [short] (3,-2.1);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)
node[transformer] (T) {};
\draw (T.B1)
to [D] (3,0)
to [R] (3,-2)
to [short] (T.B2);
\draw (3,0)
to [vR] (6,0)
to [R] (6,-2)
to [short] (3,-2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the generated circuit using the second code doesn't look good but for first code I have to use messy coordinates (2.1 etc.). Is there any way to correct this behavior so that anchors are at proper integer coordinates?

Comment: Two options: 1) use `node[transformer,yscale=<some factor>]` or 2) use `|-`-notation to determine the start and end coordinates of the vertical resistors based on the size of the transformer.

Comment: @PaulGessler are you going to write the answer? Today seems to be the day in which I wrote answers just to find comments saying exactly what I was writing.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina no time right now; go for it if you want. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **Paul Gessler** mentions in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229266/how-do-correct-the-height-of-the-transformer-in-circuitikz?noredirect=1#comment541223_229266), you can scale the transformer using some factor or, a better approach in my opinion, would be to use the perpendicular coordinate system: `(<coordinatea>|-<coordinateb>)` or `(<coordinateb>-|<coordinatea>)` to adjust the vertical/horizontal position of the coordinates:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)
node[transformer] (T) {};
\draw (T.B1)
to [D] ++(2,0)
to [R] (3,-2|-T.B2)
to [short] (T.B2);
\draw (3,0)
to [vR] (6,0)
to [R] (6,-2|-T.B2)
to [short] (3,-2|-T.B2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]